# How to create C# class from json null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization, json-serialization

I am calling API and get this response from the API.

```
{
    "StringValue": "Hi Developers",
    "TestMessage": {
        "": [
            "Enjoy Coding."
        ]
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to make my C# class.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string StringValue{ get; set; }
  public TestMessage MessageTest { get; set; }
}
public class TestMessage 
{
  [JsonProperty("")]
  public IList<string> APIResponse{ get; set; }
  //public IList<string> { get; set; }//Also try this but it gives me compilation error
}
```

but It didn't work how can I get this to work?

Comment: should MessageTest  be named TestMessage in public class MyClass?

Comment: Yes it shold be public and for data display get from the API I display that messge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can u try this

```
public class MyClass
    {
      public string StringValue{ get; set; }
      public TestMessage MessageTest { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestMessage 
    {
      [JsonProperty("")]
      public string[] APIResponse{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pradip. Firstly I try with this but it goes to `Catch` part and throw a exception of `Object not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: Hi Deep. can you share your code for converting json data to class?

Comment: Yes sure Please check this it's get call from webApi and I try to call it on load `MyClass MyClassResponse = await apiGetCall.MyAPICall();`
Can you please suggest me

Comment: Hi Deep. first get response into string. then after try this
 MyClass MyClassResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(yourresponse);

Answer (score 0):

The array is incorrect.  Try `"TestMessage": ["Enjoying Coding.", "Something else"]`. You're creating an empty element so it's confusing it.  For your object, it's named something different as well.  `MessageTest` should be `TestMessage`.  Lastly, for your actual `IList<string>`,

try `public IList<string> Messages {get;set;}`

Comment: HI Steven Actually this is not set by my side it already exists and now from other technology I migrate it to ASP.NET that's why I am not able to change message response

Comment: In that case, FiringSquadWitness is correct - Change the name of the property in MyClass from MessageTest to TestMessage and it should bind onto the correct property.

Comment: Thanks for answer I try with FiringSquadWitness with solution and tell you problem arise or not.

Comment: I try with option you suggested but it doesn't works for me.